# cancelling subscriptions on a RXJS FlatMap chain

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

For most of my RxJs subscriptions I follow the `takeWhile` approach to cancel subscriptions, as described in [this article by Brian Love](http://brianflove.com/2016/12/11/anguar-2-unsubscribe-observables/)

If I 'chain' multiple Observables using `flatMap`, should I have multiple `takeWhile`s (once for each 'hop' in the chain ? Or would one `takeWhile` suffice ? e.g. :

```
  this.dataService.awaitSomeObservable()
      .takeWhile(() => this.alive) /// <= No 1
      .flatMap(result1 => {

        //...

        return this.dataService.awaitAnotherObservable();
      })
      .takeWhile(() => this.alive) /// <= No 2 - is this necessary ????
      .subscribe(result2 => {

          //...

        }
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `takeWhile` should be enough, but you may `pipe` it (as shown bellow), if you use the latest versions (v5.5 and above) of RxJS.

```
this.dataService.awaitSomeObservable().pipe(
      takeWhile(() => this.alive), 
      flatMap(result1 => {
        //...
        return this.dataService.awaitAnotherObservable();
      })
).subscribe(x=>{})
```

You may actually put the `takeWhile` either before or after the `flatMap`, but provide an appropriate function as the argument to the `takeWhile` based on your actual usecase.

Comment: Actually, you should put the takeWhile as the last argument or you risk leaking memory from the flatMap operation - more specifically the observable from the dataService